# How to scroll recyclerview onItemClick in another recyclerview?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am building a small dictioanry app, screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw1fG.jpg)

When I click on a letter from `mRecyclerView1`, I want to scroll `mRecyclerView2` to the the first word which starts with this particular letter.

Inside the `mRecyclerView1 adapter` I've made an `interface` which gets the value of the clicked letter.
Then inside the fragment I found a workaround with `scrollToPositionWithOffset` inside the `onLetterClick` method which looks like this:

```
override fun onLetterClick(letter: String) {
    when (letter) {
        "А" -> {
            (mRecyclerView2!!.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(
                0,
                0
            )
        }
        "Б" -> {
            (mRecyclerView2!!.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(
                140,
                0
            )
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I have to add all letters from the alphabet together with the positions of the first words that start with them. And if I decide to add more words later on, these positions will be shifted and will change.

Is there a smarter way to achieve this scroll effect? If not, is it possible to make a `for/while` loop instead of using `when` with all alphabet letters?

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to maintain a `Map<String,Int>` or `Map<Char, Int>` (Your choice) which contains index of first word starting with given character. for example `("A" -> 0 , "B" -> 5 )` etc.

In your case you can prepare the map when you load the data in `RecyclerView` like following

```
val list = // This is list of words
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
list.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
     map.putIfAbsent(s[0].toString(), index)   // Handle lowercase/uppercase if required
 }
```

Now pass this `map` to your `adapter` and when any item is clicked, you can get the position of item from `map` as

```
map[word[0].toString()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection like this `Map<String, Int>`, where `String` is letter and `Int` is position,  then pass position value by letter to `onLetterClick(position: Int)` and call `scrollToPositionWithOffset(position,0)`.
IMHO it's better to use a prepared dictionary in your situation.